# Scraping 2020 Polling Data w/Mathematica?

Tags: dataset

Is there a way to use Mathematica to scrub the latest ("RCP average") [polling data](https://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2020/president/us/2020_democratic_presidential_nomination-6730.html#polls) for each of the 2020 Democratic Primary candidates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple using `Import`, select the section you want, then turn it into a dataset.

```
data = Import[
    "https://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2020/president/us/2020_\
democratic_presidential_nomination-6730.html#polls", "Data"][[2]];
ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[First[data] -> #] & /@ Rest[data]]
```

[image: dataset]

Luckily this website is structured in a way that Mathematica interprets easily.  It can be a bit trickier when they use a lot of AJAX.

Once you have the data in, there are quite a few things you can do with it.

For instance, if you want to call Biden's most recent poll:

```
pollsonly = Rest[ds]; 
biden = pollsonly[[1, "Biden"]]
```

Or if you wanted the average of his last three polls:

```
bidenlast3 = pollsonly[[1 ;; 3, "Biden"]] // Mean // N
```

Since different polls are completed at different intervals, you might not just want the most recent polls overall, but rather the most recent poll from every pollster who has completed a poll in the last 30 days.  This code would get you that:

```
recentpolls = 
  Select[pollsonly[
    All, {"Date" -> (Quiet[
         DateObject[Last[StringSplit[#, " - "]]]] &)}], 
   QuantityMagnitude[Today - #Date] < 30 &];
Values[First /@ GroupBy[recentpolls, "Poll"]][[All, "Biden"]] // 
  Mean // N
```

You could also look at movement of the candidates across a single poll:

```
politicopolls = 
  Select[pollsonly, #[[1]] == "Politico/Morning Consult Politico" &];
ListLinePlot[
 Merge[Normal[Reverse[politicopolls[[All, 3 ;; -2]]]], Identity] /. 
  "--" -> 0, PlotLabels -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> None, 
 PlotRange -> {All,All}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Poll Graph]

Lots of fun things to do.  Enjoy!

Comment: Is the best way to programatically grab, i.e., Biden's *latest* poll average `ds[2, "Biden"]`? Is there a way to use "RCP Average" instead of "2" (just in case the rows switch around on future API grabs)?

Comment: @George.  Just updated my answer to give you a few more options.